# Can I specify what dma physical address to use in Linux kernel instead of requesting one using DMA APIs?

Tags: linux-kernel, dma

Instead of using `dma_map_single()` or `kmalloc()` and `dma_map_sg()` to allocate a CPU accessible buffer then obtain IOMMU mapped dma address, can I specify a specific `dma_addr_t` type dma address and pass it to kernel to use?

The reason I have to do this is my customized hardware provides a way to calculate IOMMU mapped dma address that is available for device driver to use, but I am not sure if I can correlate this to CPU virtual memory. `dma_map_sg()` and `dma_map_single()` work in my case but I have no control over the dma address it returns (I would like to check a specific bit in dma address, and only use the address when the bit is set).

I have checked several APIs looks like `dma_map_sg()` might be able to do so... any idea is well appreciated.

Comment: You need to provide a custom structure of DMA operations.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? I think it comes down to if there is a way to tell kmalloc() to use specific dma address when allocating a contiguous buffer... but I can't find an easy way to do so... looks like have to mess around with SLAB allocator...